# Trying to remove repetitions in a paragraph using BASH

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

HI I am writing a simple BASH to remove the consecutive duplicate occurrence of any word in a paragraph separated by single space and redirecting output to stdout, here is how far I got.

> file1

```
**double double toil and trouble 
fire burn and cauldron bubble bubble 
tomorrow and tomorrow and tomorrow 
creeps in this this petty pace from day toto day**

echo `<file1` | sed -e 's/\b\([a-z ]\+\)\1/\1/g' | cat > file2
```

This is outputting in a single line as below.

```
double toil and trouble fire burn and cauldron bubble tomorrow and tomorrow creeps in this petty pace from day to day
```

and missing something as it is not correctly removing occurrences.

Comment: Just use `sed 's/\b\([a-z ]\+\)\1/\1/g' file > file2`

Comment: Problem is the 3rd line tomorrow is removed which is not correct since after 'tomorrow' there is 'and' & 4th line 'toto' is removed its not separated by a space so should not be considered consecutive duplicate.

Comment: Please read the descriptions of tags before applying them. Half of them are misplaced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed 's/\b\([a-z]\+\)\s\1\b/\1/g' file > file1
sed 's/\b\([a-z]\+\)[[:space:]]\1\b/\1/g' file > file1
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/qDh39W). The regex matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\([a-z]\+\)` - Group 1: any one or more lowercase letters
- `[[:space:]]` / `\s`  - a whitespace
- `\1` - same value as in Group 1
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: @Abelisto Yes, `I` that is supported in GNU `sed` will match in a case insensitive way.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks for the explanation. How do I just output the modified text to stdout instead of a file?

Comment: I found it, /dev/stdout